# Jupyterlab on jupyterhub

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Requirement: I require JupyterLab and JupyterHub to run side by side.. which mean both shall remain available on the click on URL, If JupyterLab (/lab) URL selected it redirects to JupyterLab or If JupyterHub (/hub) is selected it takes to Jupyter notebool (/hub) without making any manual changes.

I installed JupyterLab on a system running JupyterHub.

When I change the URL manually from /tree  to /lab it redirects between JupyterLab and JupterHub vice versa

If I set c.Spawner.default_url = '/lab' in jupyterhub_config.py it defaults takes me to JupyterLab and if don't set this it defaults goes to JupyterHub.

Question : Can I have 2 different URLs for 1) Jupterhub and 2) JupterLab without making any manual changes in URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider installing the `jupyterlab-hub` extension which will create a "Hub" tab on your JupyterLab interface that can take you to the Hub:

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/hub-extension
```

I have a production setup that is in this configuration. Users are taken to their JupyterLab interface by default, but they can access the Hub from their JupyterLab by clicking on the hub link. Once on the Hub page, the user can switch back to the JupyterLab.